# Check similarity of texts in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

I have a dataframe

```
Account      Message
454232     Hi, first example 1
321342     Now, second example
412295     hello, a new example 1 in the third row
432325     And now something completely different
```

I would like to check similarity between texts in Message column. I would need to choose one of the message as source to test (for example the first one) and create a new column with the output from similarity test.
If I had two lists, I would do as follows

```
import spacy
spacyModel = spacy.load('en')

list1 = ["Hi, first example 1"]
list2 = ["Now, second example","hello, a new example 1 in the third row","And now something completely different"]

list1SpacyDocs = [spacyModel(x) for x in list1]
list2SpacyDocs = [spacyModel(x) for x in list2]

similarityMatrix = [[x.similarity(y) for x in list1SpacyDocs] for y in list2SpacyDocs]

print(similarityMatrix)
```

But I do not know how to do the same in pandas, creating a new column with similarity results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pairwise similarity is 1) expensive, 2) not the  same shape as a column in pandas. What's your  expected result? A column for similarity with each row?

Comment: Pandas is not suited well to this task.  If your overall application strongly suggests Pandas, then you can find the handling methods [here](/questions/38286700/pandas-use-loop-to-compare-datetime-in-each-row-with-all-rows-and-saving-subset).

Comment: Hi @erip. I might consider only one column if I set one row to compare to each other, e.g. Hi, first example 1 with all the other sentences /rows. As you said, I think it would be difficult to create columns for similarity test for each row compared to each others. I would be preferable, but I think it would be very difficult. My expected output would be a new column with values that come from the example with SpaCy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about `spacy`, but in order to compare the one text with other values in the columns I would use `.apply()` and pass the match making function and set `axis=1` for column-wise. Here is an example using `SequenceMatcher` (I don't have `spacy` for now).

```
test = 'Hi, first example 1'
df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, test, x.Message).ratio(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Account                                  Message         r
0   454232                      Hi, first example 1  1.000000
1   321342                      Now, second example  0.578947
2   412295  hello, a new example 1 in the third row  0.413793
3   432325   And now something completely different  0.245614
```

So in your case, it will be a similar statement but using functions you have instead of SequenceMatcher